# sqlite3 multiple string replacement

Tags: replace, sqlite, localization

Im looking for a possibility to do a multiple string replacement for language localization.

I have a field with a text with multiple place holders like that:

"Set Point for Temperatur is changed from {%} ℃ to {%} ℃" I want to replace the {%} with a value from another field from the same row. I know there is the replace function within sqlite3. But with that I'm replacing all the place holders. But I want to replace the first {%} with a different row than the second {%}. Is that possible? I can do that programmatically in c++ or php, but it would be nice to have a solution inside the database.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can live with a different place holder, you can use [printf()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#printf):

```
select printf('%s, %s!', 'Hello', 'world');
```

Or if it is guaranteed that none or `printf`'s `%x` place holders occur in your strings, you can `replace` `{%}` with `%s` before applying `printf`.